# Cannot build cordova meteor app (Error: ENOENT)

Tags: android, cordova, meteor

I'm trying to build my android meteor app with meteor build but it gives me this error when I run the command. I should mention that deploying and meteor run work fine.

```
[sqrdcat@localhost assignr]$ meteor build ~/build2 --server=assignly.meteor.com

/home/sqrdcat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.45.t9p8sg++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: ENOENT, readdir '/home/sqrdcat/Documents/METEOR/assignr/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/android/ant-build'
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/sqrdcat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.45.t9p8sg++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    at Object.wrapper (/home/sqrdcat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.45.t9p8sg++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/tools/files.js:1330:24)
    at findApkPath (/home/sqrdcat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.45.t9p8sg++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/tools/commands.js:956:30)
    at /home/sqrdcat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.45.t9p8sg++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/tools/commands.js:941:21
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/sqrdcat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.45.t9p8sg++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at buildCommand (/home/sqrdcat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.45.t9p8sg++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/tools/commands.js:924:29)
    at Command.main.registerCommand._.extend.name [as func] (/home/sqrdcat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.45.t9p8sg++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/tools/commands.js:738:12)
    at /home/sqrdcat/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.45.t9p8sg++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/tools/main.js:1345:23
```

Comment: Have You solved this problem? I have same issue - I've tried to manually create `/ant-build` folder but then other errors appeared and after them this error came back (I came back to starting point)

Comment: Also tried that with same result. Still nothing.

Comment: Same issue last meteor version, tried with java7 and 8 no change..

Comment: same issue, does anyone found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me and I am not sure what actually solves it - but my guess is that it is a "rights" problem, because only running the commands in `sudo` mode fixed it for me:

1. `rm -rf .meteor/local/cordova-build/`
2. `sudo meteor remove-platform android`
3. `sudo meteor add-platform android`
4. `sudo meteor build .build --server http://myserver.com`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886113/meteor-android-home-is-not-set-even-though-it-is-set may be needed. I ran into issues since Meteor wasn't installed in the home directory on the root user to begin with. But reinstalling is a good idea.