# Meteor: ANDROID_HOME is not set even though it is set

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, meteor, apk

OS : Ubuntu 14.04
Framework: Meteor 1.1.0.2
Application Name: Songofy

Here's the output of `meteor install-sdk android`

```
 meteor install-sdk android
✓ Found Android bundle
✓ A JDK is installed                          
✓ Found Android Platform tools                
✓ Found Android Build Tools                   
✓ Found Android 19 API                        
✓ Found suitable Android x86 image            
✓ 'meteor' android virtual device (AVD) found 
✗ Android emulator acceleration is not installed
  (The Android emulator will be very slow without acceleration)
Platform requirements not yet met             
Please follow the instructions here:          
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Dev-Install:-Android-on-Linux#haxm
```

I cd into the Directory using

```
cd Desktop/songofy
```

Then I type `sudo add-platform android`, and it asks me to accept the eprmission and then this happens:

```
`You must agree to the terms to proceed.       

Do you agree (Y/n)? Y

/home/abhishek/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Error running /home/abhishek/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.4sddkj++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/tools/cordova-scripts/cordova.sh

/home/abhishek/.meteor/android_bundle/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
```

I add the ANDROID_HOME variable using this.

```
 abhishek@TiltedLines:~/Desktop/songofy$ export ANDROID_HOME=~/.meteor/android_bundle/android-sdk
 abhishek@TiltedLines:~/Desktop/songofy$ export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
 abhishek@TiltedLines:~/Desktop/songofy$ export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

What is the problem with Cordova and Meteor?

Comment: You should add your export statements to your `.bashrc` so they they're run every time you open the terminal. This might be the solution to your problem

Comment: I tried this [meteor solution](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Dev-Install:-Android-on-Linux#libs32). It worked for the first error, meaning all ticks for the installation part but I am still not getting it to run android.
`ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.` I still get error when I try to add android platform. The `ANDROID_HOME` is set and android command is also working. I am just starting on meteor and this is a big deal-breaker for me. Have you solved this? I am using Ububtu 15.0.2 BTW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a permission issue. Because the android is installed as a user and the environment variable were set for the user, sudo cannot access the variables.

So what I did is

```
sudo -E su
```

I am using this to transfer the environment variables for root user. I run `meteor` it installs meteor for root. do a `meteor install-sdk android` it installs the `sdk` for root as well, then run `sudo add-platform android`. Root has both meteor and the android sdk now, so the app runs.

Hope this helps. Wasted a lot of time on this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble with below environment:

- Meteor 1.5
- Android SDK tools 26
- `$ANDROID_HOME` was set properly

Here is how I fixed:

- remove `Android SDK tools 26`
- get `Android SDK tools 25.2.3` (https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.3-linux.zip)
- unzip it to `$ANDROID_HOME/tools`
- run `SDK manager` by `$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android`
- install `SDK Platform` 25.3 (Android 7.1.1 API 25)